# Swift core data fetch relationship objects of parent error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I got a core data error, here's my models setting.

[Item Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwbhQ.jpg)

[Item NSManaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRrH7.jpg)

[Person Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfx3q.jpg)

[Person NSManaged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KrTH.jpg)

I can success to save objects, and view in database app.

```
private func saveObjects() {
    
    var items = [Item]()
    let person = Person(context: self.context)
    let item = Item(context: self.context)
    
    item.car = "Mazda"
    item.phone = "iPhone"
    item.person = person
    items.append(item)
    
    person.name = "Sally"
    person.location = "South"
    person.items = items
    
    do {
        try self.context.save()
    } catch {
        print("saveObjects Error:", error)
    }
    
}
```

[View Item data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quZTT.jpg)

[View Person data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HUrW.jpg)

But when i fetch person objects, i got some errors.

```
private func fetchObjects() {
    
    do {
        
        let fetchPersons: [Person] = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
        let fetchItems: [Item] = try context.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
        
    } catch {
        print("fetchObjects Error:", error)
    }
    
}
```

Some errors:

> fetchObjects Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error occurred." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80}

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.807951+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.808238+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] -[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.808637+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })
> CoreData: fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.808854+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] CoreData: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.809115+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af8540> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af8540> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.818265+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.818633+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.818863+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] -[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.819103+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })
> CoreData: fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.819281+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] CoreData: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.819503+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af0620> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af0620> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.819638+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.819881+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.820054+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] -[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.820236+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })
> CoreData: fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.820404+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] CoreData: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.820611+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af0620> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af0620> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.820735+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: -executeRequest: encountered exception =  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo = {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.831015+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.831202+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] -[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.831394+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })
> CoreData: fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.831553+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] CoreData: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch  threw while decoding a value. ({
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> })

> 2021-12-28 11:09:33.831747+0800 APNsPrototype[12846:625492] [error] error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af42a0> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }
> CoreData: error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600001af42a0> ,  threw while decoding a value. with userInfo of {
> NSUnderlyingException = "-[Item initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000036a5b80";
> }

If i fetch items, it's work and success, but fetch person is wrong.

I tried few days :(, if i thinking wrong please tell me, thanks!

Comment: Post errors and code as text and not images. My guess is that it has something to do with the `items` property you have added to your Person class that doesn't exist in the entity.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks your reply, i edit some error code. I found when i use custom object or custom objects array set Transformable type then error.
Use native type like [Double] then fetch data success. But i don't know why.

Comment: You can’t have an @NSManaged property in your class that doesn’t exist in the entity

Comment: I got point! I originlly thought must manual add items attributes to save item in Person, it's wrong. Relationships item already create it. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.